# Automate the generate script in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We can generate the scripts for all database objects manually but I want to automate this process. Is there anyway to generate scripts at a specific interval of time or can we set a job to execute to generate scripts in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Please explain what kind of script you would like to automate? DDL or DML? Or both?

Comment: OT - [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434545/how-to-generate-sql-scripts-using-smo-scripter. The PowerShell script can be scheduled via a SQL Agent job.

Comment: You can use `SqlPackage.EXE` to generate a .dacpac if that is acceptable. Like any command line tool it can be scheduled in SQL Agent.